# Append localstorage form data on next page using jquery only

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have two pages say "form.html" and "data.html".
In "**form.html**" i have the below html and jquery code:

**html:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label>Enter Name: <input type="text" id="txtName" /></label>
    <button id="_save">Save</button>
</form>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#_save").on('click', function() {
        localStorage.name = $('#txtName').val();
        console.log("data saved");
    });
});
```

Where as in **"data.html"** i have the below code:

**html:**

```
<div id="dataContainer"></div>
```

**"jquery:"**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData();
});

function loadData() {
    $('#dataContainer').append('<div><h5>' + localStorage.name + '</h5></div>');
    localStorage.removeItem(name);
}
```

***Current situation:*** in **form.html** i am trying to store form data using click fn and localstorage. Where as in **data.html** i'm trying to get the stored data on document ready function. where as previous data is deleted and newly entered data is loading.

***Problem:***
I am trying to append the all names in **data.html** which are stored in **form.html** page. I need all the names which are entered previously. (previously entered data should not deleted.) 
please help me where i am missing or any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can append previously saved data with new one  and read it in next page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#_save").on('click', function() {
        //append previously saved data with comma separator
        localStorage.name = localStorage.name + "," + $('#txtName').val();
        console.log("data saved");
    });
});
```

and remove below line from loadData function
`localStorage.removeItem(name);`

Comment: Thank you so much, works great.
will accept this as answer in few mins.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar : I modified my scenario too.. helpful solution

Comment: @Kulfi, happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Store it in an array. Then retrieve it and display.

```
// First click function
$("#_save").on('click', function() {
  names = localStorage.names;
  if(names){
    //names found

    // convert names into an array
    names = JSON.parse(names);
  } else {
    //names not found so start with a new array
    names = [];
  }

  //get new name
  new_name = $('#txtName').val();

  //push new name into the names array
  names.push(new_name);

  //save names array to localstorage
  localStorage.names = JSON.stringify(names);

  console.log("data saved");
});


// Load data function
function loadData() {
  // Get localstorage names
  names = localStorage.names;
  if(names){
    // convert names into an array
    names = JSON.parse(names);
  } else {
    //if no names found
    names = [];
  }

  if(names.length){
    // loop through the array to print all names
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
      // get the individual name
      name = names[i];

      //pring name
      $('#dataContainer').append('<div><h5>' + name + '</h5></div>');
    }
  } else {
    // no names found in the array
    $('#dataContainer').append('<div><h5>No names found!</h5></div>');
  }
}
```